# sql 2008 support for SqlCacheDependency?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

according to : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx

if im using sql 2005 i have to write this :

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Northwind" connectionString="Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=northwind; Integrated Security=true"; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <caching>
      <sqlCacheDependency enabled = "true" pollTime = "60000" >
        <databases>
          <add name="northwind" 
            connectionStringName="Northwind"
            pollTime="9000000"
            />
        </databases>
      </sqlCacheDependency>
    </caching>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

but what about sql 2008?
i'm enabling the service broker ,

i'm creating sqlCacheDpendency and put there the Command

and when i change the Table , it doesn't remove the cached item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) to understand how it works and then you can understand how to [troubleshoot](http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/) it (or cheat out with [`ssbdiagnose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934450.aspx)). Most likely the EXECUTE AS context of the database was invalidated by orphaning the dbo due to database movement. The `transmission_status` value in `sys.transmission_queue` would clearly show it. If true, the fix is to map dbo to a valid login:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<dbname>] TO [sa];
```

Otherwise the solution depends o the problem cause, use the troubleshooting steps linked above.

Comment: i will read it , but Do i need this xml in web.config ? ( sql 2008)